# How to read two words and then a line from an fstream in C++?

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I ran into a bit of a problem when coding in C++. I have an input (a file that is going to be read by `fstream`):

```
1 2
three four five six
```

What I want to do with this input is: take the first line, and split it into two `string` variables : one with 1, and one with 2. After that, for the next line, I want to use some form of `getline()` possibly to get "three four five six" as one `string`. I've currently tried this: I have some code that declares three string vars:

```
#include<string>
// Main function...
string str1, str2, str3;
fstream inf;
inf.open('somefile.txt');
inf >> str1 >> str2 >> str3;
inf.close();
```

This code takes the "1" and "2" correctly, but it only takes the first character of the next line. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::getline()` after ignoring the `\n` using `ignore()` to get the whole line as string as follows

```
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    std::string str1, str2, str3;
    std::fstream inf;
    inf.open("somefile.txt");
    inf >> str1 >> str2;
    inf.ignore();
    std::getline(inf, str3);
    inf.close();

    //Displying them
    std::cout<<str1<<" "<<str2<<" "<<str3;
    }
```